# Querying object arrays with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mern

Let's say I have such a collection in mongoose I have such a template

```
[
  {
    id: 123,
    "arrayvalue": [
      {
        id: 355,
        name: "jhon",
        job: true
      },
      {
        id: 155,
        name: "clarck",
        job: false
      },
      {
        id: 275,
        name: "orie",
        job: true
      },
      
    ]
  }
]
```

I am currently using nodejs express

All I want to do is get objects whose value is true only.

I want the output to be like this

```
[
  { id : 123,
    "arrayvalue": [
      {
        "id": 355,
        "job": true,
        "name": "jhon"
      },
      {
        "id": 275,
        "job": true,
        "name": "orie"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I searched in many places and could not find it, I hope it is necessary for the project. you can help

I use : "mongoose": "^5.12.2"

Comment: What does your query currently look like?

Answer (score 0):

**Option - 1**

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/z1BwqmFh7Nq

[$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

[$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/)

[$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

[$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{ $unwind: "$arrayvalue" }, // break into individual documents
{ $match: { "arrayvalue.job": true } }, // match query
{
  $group: { // join the document back
    _id: "$_id",
    arrayvalue: { $push: "$arrayvalue"}
  }
}])
```

---

**Option - 2**

if you want to do it in JS :-

```js
const data = [{
  id: 123,
  "arrayvalue": [{
      id: 355,
      name: "jhon",
      job: true
    },
    {
      id: 155,
      name: "clarck",
      job: false
    },
    {
      id: 275,
      name: "orie",
      job: true
    },

  ]
}]

const arr = data.map((d) => {
  if (d.arrayvalue) {
    d.arrayvalue = d.arrayvalue.filter(e => e.job === true);
  }
  return d;
});
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: I would be glad if you specify how I can adapt this express and mongoose.

Comment: @Ellezbayramov check https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj ={
    id : 123,
    arrayvalue : [
     
        {
     id : 355,
    name : "jhon",
    job : true
        },
        {
     id : 155,
    name : "clarck",
    job : false
        },
        {
     id : 275,
    name : "orie",
    job : true
        },
    ]
};
    
    var response = {}; 
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.arrayvalue.length; i++) {
      if (obj.arrayvalue[i].job) {
        response[i] = obj.arrayvalue[i];
      }
    }
    console.log(response);
```